# Jenkins Springboot Pipeline

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jenkins

I'm trying to make automatic build and test for my Spring boot application.

Here is application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
  use-forward-headers: true
  display-name: targcontrol-cloud-employee-management

spring:
  application:
    name: employee-management
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/targcontrol_cloud_employee_management
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  rabbitmq:
      host: localhost
      port: 5672
      username: guest
      password: guest
```

I have multiple tests that require Postgres (with the database) and Rabbit to be launched before testing.

If I launch everything on my local machine with docker commands:

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=targcontrol_cloud_employee_management postgres
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq
```

everything works fine, spring boot can see Postgres.

Here is my jenkinsfile for pipeline

```
 node {
        stage 'Checkout'
            checkout scm

        stage 'Build'
            sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'


        stage 'Test'
            docker.image('postgres').withRun('-p 5432:5432 -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres" -e "POSTGRES_DB=targcontrol_cloud_employee_management"') { c ->
              sleep 60;                
              sh 'mvn test'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
                }
            }
    }
```

If I run that configuration inside Jenkins I can see the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

It looks like Jenkins can't see postgres in docker.
Jenkins itself also was launched in docker.

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /home/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -u root jenkins
```

Comment: Are you sure the database has been started by the time the `mvn test` is being executed? From the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers) it appears that you should run some kind of loop until the service has actually started.

Comment: I added  sleep 60; but still same error.
I can see with my docker that there is a docker container postgres with the database and I can connect to it. Looks like inside docker -p 5432:5432 is now working...

Comment: maybe you can create a docker-compose in which you run your maven command depending on a Postgres or any other services. then you can just use the docker-compose to run your tests.

Comment: I understood how to do it. Have to add network bridge between containers.

sh "docker network create -d bridge test-pipeline"
ocker.image("postgres").withRun("-p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=targcontrol_cloud_employee_management --network test-pipeline --name db")